# data visualization (2-d plot) package for smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

Is there any current data visualization or 2-d plot package for smalltalk (squeak or pharo) platform?

something similar to d3js or processing.org, or maybe sdl support to draw lines/dots on the screen?

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at [roassal](/questions/tagged/roassal). While it is not exactly similar to d3js or procressing.org it is an interactive visualization engine with a nice DSL called Mondrian to script visualizations.

For further information look at:

- the [Roassal homepage](http://objectprofile.com/#/pages/products/roassal/overview.html),
- the recent examples on it's creators [facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/ObjectProfile),
- and the Roassal and Mondrian chapters in [Deep into Pharo](http://www.deepintopharo.com).

Comment: And the Roassal guys are very friendly and helpful

Answer (score 4):

Graph-ET might be what you are looking for: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkKNALQHa88

Comment: Yes, and GraphET is built on top of Roassal too.